# Is there a way to be notified when an MSI-based installation is starting?

Tags: windows-installer, hook

I write plugins for a third-party MSI-based product. Unfortunately, because our customizations connect to a database used by this product and also depend on some services of this product, our customizations interfere with upgrading the core software to a newer version. We have looked at the various options for working around this and the easiest would seem to be if we can detect when the upgrade installation starts. Is there a way to be notified when an MSI-based installation is starting?

Comment: Edited tags, this sounds like an issue you would tackle with the Windows Installer API - might be worth editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

What type of plugins are you creating? Are you referring to merge modules?

Usually old products are detected through [Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table. You define an upgrade rule for older versions which saves them in an installer property. This property can then be used to determine if an older version was found.

Another approach is a custom action which tries to find installed products which have the same UpgradeCode as the MSI.

Windows Installer doesn't send notifications. It just provides information. It's up to you to read that information from installer properties or through a custom action.

Comment: No, not merge modules. The application is not one I can control in any way. It is a third-party commercial product. By plugins, I mean Windows services which make use of the APIs offered by this third-party product.

Comment: In this case the upgrade must be handled by the package developer. The installed files cannot control or detect an upgrade. An alternative is for you to create a merge module which handles the upgrade any way you want (for example stop the services). This merge module can then be used by the package developer.